# CouchDB: Unable to start CouchDB normally

Tags: couchdb, ubuntu-14.04

I am a newbie to couchDB. Recently, I have dived into it with a quick installation instruction over here:

```
sudo apt-get update -y

sudo apt-get install g++ -y
sudo apt-get install erlang-base erlang-dev erlang-eunit erlang-nox -y
sudo apt-get install libmozjs185-dev libicu-dev libcurl4-gnutls-dev libtool -y

curl -O http://apache.mirrors.tds.net/couchdb/source/1.5.1/apache-couchdb-1.5.1.tar.gz
tar -zxvf apache-couchdb-1.5.1.tar.gz 
cd apache-couchdb-1.5.1

./configure
make
sudo make install

sudo adduser --disabled-login --disabled-password --no-create-home couchdb

sudo chown -R couchdb:couchdb /usr/local/var/log/couchdb
sudo chown -R couchdb:couchdb /usr/local/var/lib/couchdb
sudo chown -R couchdb:couchdb /usr/local/var/run/couchdb

sudo ln -s /usr/local/etc/logrotate.d/couchdb /etc/logrotate.d/couchdb
sudo ln -s /usr/local/etc/init.d/couchdb  /etc/init.d

sudo update-rc.d couchdb defaults


1. modify /usr/local/etc/couchdb/local.ini
2. change bindAddress to 0.0.0.0
3. reboot
4. remember to go into the config settings and secure server
5. remember to turn on auto compaction
```

I have followed exactly the guide, except the 4th and 5th steps cause I did not know how to do it. When I ran:

```
couchdb
```

I got the following message in the terminal (I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS):

```
Apache CouchDB 1.5.1 (LogLevel=info) is starting.
Error opening log file /usr/local/var/log/couchdb/couch.log: permission denied{"init terminating in do_boot",{{badmatch,{error,{bad_return,{{couch_app,start,[normal,["/usr/local/etc/couchdb/default.ini","/usr/local/etc/couchdb/local.ini"]]},{'EXIT',{{badmatch,{error,{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,couch_primary_services,{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,couch_log,{error,"permission denied","/usr/local/var/log/couchdb/couch.log"}}}}}}},[{couch_server_sup,start_server,1,[{file,"couch_server_sup.erl"},{line,98}]},{application_master,start_it_old,4,[{file,"application_master.erl"},{line,269}]}]}}}}}},[{couch,start,0,[{file,"couch.erl"},{line,18}]},{init,start_it,1,[]},{init,start_em,1,[]}]}}
Crash dump was written to: erl_crash.dump
init terminating in do_boot ()
```

May anyone help me figure out this problem and suggest some solution to fix it? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to make a note here for how I fixed this problem in my environment.  In my case, the `/opt/couchdb/data` folder was a symlink to `/var/lib/couchdb`.  No matter what I tried I would get a permission denied error at startup, even though all the files seemed to be owned by user `couchdb`.

I eventually figured out that the "execute" permission was not set on `/var/lib`.  Without this permission the symlink would not work.  If you run into this problem, start by setting `chmod -R a+x /var` as I did, to prevent this from happening.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to start the `couchdb` process as the `couchdb` user, with `su couchdb -c ./couchdb` (assuming the current directory contains the executable) - double-check the `su` command options for your system.

Also, check the permissions on `/usr/local/var/log/couchdb/couch.log` - make sure it is writeable by the `couchdb` user.

Answer (score 0):

Although on CentOS, the "problem" is avoided using `service couchdb [start|status|stop|restart]`.

Answer (score 0):

https://medium.com/@tomiwatech_45998/installing-couchdb-on-ubuntu-17-10-18148e2eb846

Hi there, 
this helped me resolve the issue and solved the problem. My ubuntu version is 16.04 and i downloaded couchdb-1.7.0 version.

Answer (score -1):

You can start couchdb using  below command

sudo couchdb stop

sudo couchdb start

Comment: DON'T DO THIS!! This will mess up all your permissions and you will never be able to run couchdb without root rights again (unless you completely reinstall couchdb) Use the "couchdb" user instead